# ClickOnce from web showing annoying “Launching Application” window every time I run it

Tags: .net, web, installation, clickonce

Every time when I click and launch Click-Once application from my website, I see a "verifying application requirement" window. window for few seconds and it got disappeared.

Weather there is an update or no update, it first launches the popup and disappears if no update, if there is an update then it continues to download.

I hope this is may be because, we point the URL to server .application file, and it may tries to check weather it is already installed or not in local.

However anybody has tried to remove this window, even if it checks in background it is fine, but i do not want the window to be appeared in UI or is there anyway that i can avoid by writing some custom installer code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can not. It doesn't matter whether you keep the application online or install it locally, there's always this window first, then either updates are installed or the application is launched directly.